# How to install Hbase on Windows 7

Tags: jasper-reports, hbase, jasperserver

Does anyone knows how to install HBase on windows 7 and then i want to connect Hbase to Jasper report server and Ireport, How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are pretty distinct questions. Microsoft has been increasing their support for Hadoop. But I haven't heard anything specific to HBase on Windows. You probably already found [Installing HBase on Windows using Cygwin](http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html) on apache.org. I don't know of anything else.

To get iReport and JasperReports Server connected to HBase, refer to the documentation and the downloadable HBase connector on the jasperforge.org [big data project](http://jasperforge.org/projects/bigdatareportingfornosqlandhadoop).

Comment: Working link: http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/hadoop-connectors
The connector is out of date though. See this for an up-to-date approach: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-use-apache-phoenix-jdbc-driver-run-reports-hbase